# Angular interceptors order with interceptor in imported module

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I undertand anguler interceptors are executed according to their declaration order in a module.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: FirstInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: SecondInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

FirstInterceptor will be executed before SecondInterceptor.

But what about the order when an interceptor is in a imported Module ?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  exports: [...],
})
export class ImportedModule{
  static forRoot() {
    return {
      ngModule: ImportedModule,
      providers: [
        ...,
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: ThirdInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        }
      ],
    };
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    ImportedModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [
  ...
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: FirstInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: SecondInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

According to my tests, the imported module interceptor (ThirdInterceptor) is executed after the AppModule interceptors.

In my situation, it's not the expected behavior, I want the imported module interceptor to be executed first, is it possible ?

Comment: it's possible by providing all of your interceptors in the same module.

Comment: of course, but in my case, the other interceptor is in another package, it's not in my source code and I don't want to maintain it. I Just want to change the order.

Comment: an interceptor in a third party package is suspect. i'd be weary of such a package.

Comment: well, it's not suspect in my case, it's maintained by another team of my organisation.

Comment: eh, just because it's trusted doesn't mean it's not suspect. it's poor design IMO to implement an interceptor in a package that's designed to be used as a library.

Comment: this, maybe :) the other package is handling authentication. Is it possible for the other module to just expose the interceptor, and to declare it in my AppModule ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211508/discussion-between-crieloue-gilles-and-bryan60).